# Mapper library for xml to java objects

Tags: jaxb

We are creating jaxb classes for a predefined schema. The schema contains certain elements which uses xs:choice to create complexTypes. In this case the binding being generated contain a List which makes it complex as we have to identify the actual instance and then cast it. We tried using the binding customization attribute "choiceContentProperty="false"" to change this behavior. But this does not seem to work. Any suggestions to override this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of [`jaxb2-simplify-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin).

---

This is a use case for the [`jaxb2-simplify-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin).

This:

```
<xs:complexType name="typeWithElementsProperty">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:choice> 
</xs:complexType>
```

Normally generates this:

```
@XmlElements({
    @XmlElement(name = "foo", type = String.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "bar", type = Integer.class),
})
protected List<Serializable> fooOrBar;
```

But with [`jaxb2-simplify-plugin`](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin) you'll get this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "foo", type = String.class)
protected List<String> foo;
@XmlElement(name = "bar", type = Integer.class)
protected List<Integer> bar;
```